# How do I center my mobile menu's contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

They're aligning left and apparently I'm not smart enough to figure this out. Generally, how would I change its alignment? Center it, for example?

Additionally, if I wanted to expand the size of each item in the instance that the screen is < 950 px, I would do that as conditional formatting under the relevant media query portion of my CSS, right?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'IMG') {
      //context menu attempt on top of an image element
      return false;
    }
  });
  //dropdown nav
  $("#nav").addClass("js");
  $("#nav").addClass("js").before('<div id="menu">☰</div>');
  $("#menu").click(function() {
    $("#nav").toggle();
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 950) {
      $("#nav").removeAttr("style");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #c5e8ea;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#navmain {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #E5E5E5;
  background-color: #000000;
  box-shadow: ;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: .8;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  opacity: ;
  color: #E5E5E5;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

ul.navmain {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}

li.navmain {
  float: left;
}

a.navmain:link,
a.navmain:visited {
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  width: 110px;
  font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #E5E5E5;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 95px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

a.navmain:hover,
a.navmain:active {
  background-color: #181818;
}

.active {
  background-color: #0b0b0a;
}

#content1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 6s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 6s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 6s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 6s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 6s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Firefox < 16 */

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Internet Explorer */

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Opera < 12.1 */

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#content2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

#content2 h1 {
  margin-top: 95px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

#content2 p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 45px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  float: left;
}

#content3 {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

#content3 img {}

#footer {
  clear: both;
  height: 15px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #E5E5E5;
  border-top: 1 px solid #efefef;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  line-height: 15px;
  background-color: #0b0b0a;
}

#footer a {
  color: #E5E5E5;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#footer a:hover {
  Color: #db6d16
}

#footer #altnav {
  width: 350px;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}


/* dropdown nav */

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  #menu {
    width: 1.4em;
    display: block;
    background: ;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
  }
  #nav.js {
    display: none;
  }
  ul {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
  }
  li {
    width: 100%;
    border-right: none;
  }
  #content2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  #content2 h1 {
    margin-top: 95px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 950px) {
  #menu {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* dropdown nav */
```

```html
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700');
</style>
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive');
</style>
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Old+Standard+TT:400i');
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="navmain">
  <div id="header">
    <a href="#">
      <h1>Some Dude</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="navmain" id="nav">
    <li class="navmain"><a class="navmain" href="#">fauna</a></li>
    <li class="navmain"><a class="navmain" href="#">flora</a></li>
    <li class="navmain"><a class="navmain" href="#">scenic</a></li>
    <li class="navmain"><a class="navmain" href="#">urban</a></li>
    <li class="navmain"><a class="navmain" href="#">about</a></li>
    <li class="navmain"><a class="navmain" href="#">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your margins.

```
a.navmain:link, a.navmain:visited {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

New code snippet:

```css
html, body{
font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #c5e8ea;
background-color:#000000;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);


}


.hidden {
 display: none;
}

p {
 text-align: justify;
}


#header {
 position:fixed;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 4px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
 z-index:1;
}

#navmain {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height:75px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;
 font-size:25px;
 color:#E5E5E5;
 background-color: #000000;
 box-shadow: ;
 padding: 0px;
 z-index:1;
 opacity:.8;

}

h1 {
 margin:0;
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-top:0px;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 opacity:;
 color:#E5E5E5;
 text-shadow:
       3px 3px 0 #000,
     -1px -1px 0 #000,  
      1px -1px 0 #000,
      -1px 1px 0 #000,
       1px 1px 0 #000;
 
}


 ul.navmain {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:right;
 }

 li.navmain {
  float:left;
 }

 a.navmain:link,a.navmain:visited {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:block;
  height:75px;
  width:110px;
  font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  color:#E5E5E5;
  background-color:#000000;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:95px;
  padding:0px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:lowercase;
  
 }

 a.navmain:hover,a.navmain:active {
  background-color:#181818;
 }

.active {
    background-color: #0b0b0a;
}




#content1 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 background-color: #000000;
 background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
   -webkit-animation: fadein 6s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 6s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 6s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 6s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 6s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
   }

   /* Firefox < 16 */
   @-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
   }

   /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
   @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
   }

   /* Internet Explorer */
   @-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
   }

   /* Opera < 12.1 */
   @-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
   }   
   
#content2 {
 position:absolute;
 width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
 background-color: #000000;
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
 
}

#content2 h1 {
 margin-top:95px;
 padding:10px;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; 
}

#content2 p {
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-left:45px;
 margin-right:45px; 
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 float:left;
}

#content3 {
 float:right;
 width:40%;
 height:100%;
}

#content3 img {
 
}

#footer {
 clear: both;
 height: 15px;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #E5E5E5;
 
 border-top: 1 px solid #efefef;
 padding: 8px 10px;
 line-height: 15px;
 background-color:#0b0b0a;
}

#footer a {
 color: #E5E5E5;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#footer a:hover {
 Color: #db6d16
}

#footer  #altnav {
 width: 350px;
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
}

/* dropdown nav */
@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  #menu {
   width:1.4em;
   display: block;
   background:;
   font-size:1.35em;
   text-align: center;
   float:right;
  }
  #nav.js {
   display: none;
  }
  ul {
   width:100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color:#000000;
  
  }
  li {
   width:100%;
   border-right:none;
  
  }
  #content2 {
   position:absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #000000;
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   
  }

  #content2 h1 {
   margin-top:95px;
   padding:10px;
   font-size: 40px;
   font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; 
  }
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 950px) {
  #menu {
   display: none;
  }
}
/* dropdown nav */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>| Home</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
  <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">
  <style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700');</style>
  <style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive');</style>
  <style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Old+Standard+TT:400i');</style>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "css/master.css";</style> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
     if(e.target.nodeName == 'IMG'){
      //context menu attempt on top of an image element
      return false;
     }
    });
    //dropdown nav
    $("#nav").addClass("js");
    $("#nav").addClass("js").before('<div id="menu">☰</div>');
    $("#menu").click(function(){
     $("#nav").toggle();
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
     if(window.innerWidth > 950) {
      $("#nav").removeAttr("style");
     }
    });
   });
  </script>
 </head> 

 <body>
  
   <div id="navmain">
    <div id="header">
    <a href="#"><h1>Some Dude</h1></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="navmain" id="nav">
     <li class="navmain"><a class="navmain" href="#">fauna</a></li>
     <li class="navmain"><a class="navmain" href="#">flora</a></li>
     <li class="navmain"><a class="navmain" href="#">scenic</a></li>
     <li class="navmain"><a class="navmain" href="#">urban</a></li>
     <li class="navmain"><a class="navmain" href="#">about</a></li>
     <li class="navmain"><a class="navmain" href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>   
   </div>
   <div id="content1">
   </div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah! Duh. Thank you very much. So simple!